# multiple tables in android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to use two tables in my SQLite database but when I try to read the second table my app crashes.

I have a table for the items in a storage and another table for the employees of the storage.

Here is my database class:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Storage";
protected static final String KEY_ID = "id";
protected static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
protected static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
protected static final String KEY_ORIGIN = "origin";
protected static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
protected static final String KEY_BRAND = "brand";
protected static final String TAB_NAME = "items";

protected static final String KEY_ID2 = "id2";
protected static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";
protected static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
protected static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
protected static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
protected static final String TAB_NAME2 = "employees";
protected static final int VERSION = 1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TAB_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_ORIGIN + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_BRAND + " TEXT)";

    String CREATE_DIPENDENTI_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TAB_NAME2 + " ("
            + KEY_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DIPENDENTI_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TAB_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TAB_NAME2);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void Add(String des, String cat, String pro, String data, String brand) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, des);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, cat);
    contentValues.put(KEY_ORIGIN, pro);
    contentValues.put(KEY_DATE, data);
    contentValues.put(KEY_BRAND, brand);

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TAB_NAME,null, contentValues);

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

public void Add(String cog, String nom, String user, String pass) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_SURNAME, cog);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, nom);
    contentValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
    contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass);

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TAB_NAME2,null, contentValues);

    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

public Cursor getInfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TAB_NAME + ";";
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public ArrayList getInfoDip() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TAB_NAME2, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("surname")));
        al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username")));
        al.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return al;
}

public void Modify(int cod,String des, String cat, String pro, String dat, String bran){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    if(!des.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME+" SET description = "+"'"+des+"' "+ "WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!cat.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME+" SET categoria = "+"'"+cat+"' "+ "WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!pro.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME+" SET origin = "+"'"+pro+"' "+ "WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!dat.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME+" SET date = "+"'"+dat+"' "+ "WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!bran.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME+" SET brand = "+"'"+bran+"' "+ "WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"'");
}

public void Modify(int cod, String cog, String nom, String user, String pass){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    if(!cog.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME2+" SET surname = "+"'"+cog+"' "+ "WHERE id2 = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!nom.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME2+" SET name = "+"'"+nom+"' "+ "WHERE id2 = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!user.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME2+" SET username = "+"'"+user+"' "+ "WHERE id2 = "+"'"+cod+"'");
    if(!pass.isEmpty())
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TAB_NAME2+" SET password = "+"'"+pass+"' "+ "WHERE id2 = "+"'"+cod+"'");
}

public void Delete(int cod){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TAB_NAME+" WHERE id= "+"'"+cod+"'");
}

public void DeleteDip(int cod){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TAB_NAME2+" WHERE id2= "+"'"+cod+"'");
}

public Cursor Search(int cod){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TAB_NAME + " WHERE id = "+"'"+cod+"';";
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public Cursor Search(String des){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TAB_NAME + " WHERE description = "+"'"+des+"';";
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public void DeleteAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + TAB_NAME);
}
}
```

and here is the activity where I try to get the `ArrayList` with the data:

```
private Database db= new Database(this);
private ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    db.Add("admin","admin","admin","admin");
    al.addAll(db.getInfoDip());
```

But when I try to put the data in the `ArrayList` the app crashes. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Add the log for the crash.

Comment: If you created the 2nd table after you first ran the app you must uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate the db and the tables. If the problem persists try in a clean device.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. android studio is just an IDE which is _helping_ you to _develop_ in android. your question therefore has nothing to do with android studio, but rather with android. so i've updated your question title :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well so far, how I learned that the best practice for formating queries is to use String.format function. Here your example:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TAB_NAME + ";";
```

Best practice:

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", TAB_NAME);
```

So let's get to the getInfoDip method, you should try this:

```
   public List<ContentValues> getInfoDip() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", TAB_NAME2);
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        List<ContentValues> list = new ArrayList<>(res.getCount());
        while (!res.isAfterLast()){
            String surname = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_SURNAME));
            String name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
            String username = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME));
            String password = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
            list.add(new ContentValues(surname, name, username, password));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Here is my whole SQLite test program, check out maybe it helps you:

```
package com.example.vezba09;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_FILE_NAME = "contact_database";

    public Database(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_FILE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = String.format(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                ContactModel.TABLE_NAME,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE
        );
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        String query = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", ContactModel.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Dodavanje kontakta
    public void addContact(String name, String email, String phone) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, name);
        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE, phone);

        db.insert(ContactModel.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    //Izmena
    public void editContact(int contactId, String name, String email, String phone) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, name);
        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE, phone);

        db.update(ContactModel.TABLE_NAME,
                cv,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)});
    }

    public int deleteContact(int contactId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(ContactModel.TABLE_NAME,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)});
    }

    public ContactModel getContactById(int contactId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?",
                ContactModel.TABLE_NAME,
                ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID);

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)});
        if(res.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME));
            String email = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL));
            String phone = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE));
            return new ContactModel(contactId, name, email, phone);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<ContactModel> getAllContacts() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", ContactModel.TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        List<ContactModel> list = new ArrayList<>(res.getCount());
        while(!res.isAfterLast()) {
            int contactId = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID));
            String name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME));
            String email = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL));
            String phone = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ContactModel.COLUMN_CONTACT_PHONE));

            list.add(new ContactModel(contactId, name, email, phone));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Try this and feel free to ask more questions :)

Best regards, Sanady

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately, the command list.add(new ContentValues(surname, name, username, password));  gives me the error Cannot resolve constructor 'ContentValues(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'. Do you know why?

Comment: Hey, well the issue is that I am assigning retrieved values to an object, that's also best practice, so you should create object ContentValues with a constructor, getters, and setters. After that, the code should work fine :)

Comment: Hey, thanks again, now it doesn't show compiler errors, but how do I get the list in the activity? I tried creating a new list and then using the command listUser.addAll(db.getInfoDip()); but isn't working :(

Comment: If you want to get a list of all ContentValues then you should do next: List<ContentValues> contentValueList = getInfoDip(); Following code means that you initialize an empty list and then you assign fetched values from the database into your newly created list. :)